# Powershell search subfolders for specific folder and copy

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item

I'm trying to write a powershell scripts to search a folder and its subfolders for a specific folder from a csv file and then copy that folder elsewhere.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$filePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
    [string]$InstanceName
)

Import-CSV -Delim ',' -Path $filePath  | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Folder\$InstanceName -Directory -Recurse
    Copy-Item $_.FOLDERNAME d:\CopyFolder\$InstanceName -recurse
}
```

That seems to run forever and obviously errors a lot because the files aren't there when it tries to copy. Is there a way to just use Copy-Item if I don't know the specific path? OR some other alternative way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

- You can use the -filter parameter to search for the particular folder
- Pipe the results of your get-childitem so that it only tries to do a
  copy-item when it finds a folder
- Use the FullName property when using the -recurse parameter on get-childitem to ensure the full path to the item is always used

  ```
  Import-CSV -Delim ',' -Path $filePath  | ForEach-Object {
      Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Folder\$InstanceName -Recurse -Directory -Filter $_.FOLDERNAME | ForEach-Object {
          Copy-Item $_.FullName d:\CopyFolder\$InstanceName -Recurse
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I want to copy the folder and the items in it, not the file. That is why I should use recurse correct?

Comment: @Shawn Yes sorry, updated answer.. Your CSV column header of FILENAME contains the names of folders? That's a little misleading